# Python modifies the metadata of GCP storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Now I have a requirement. Whenever I upload and create a new storage object, I need to modify the metadata of all storage objects. For this, I use GCP's Function to achieve this.

Let storage be the trigger of Function. Every time a new storage object is uploaded, the function will be used to modify the metadata of all objects. The code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def hello_gcs(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Set storage all blob's metadata."""
    bucket_name = 'gcpresource'
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
      blob = bucket.get_blob(blob.name)
      CACHE_CONTROL="public, max-age=60480000"
      blob.cache_control = CACHE_CONTROL
      blob.patch()
      print("The metadata for the blob {} is {}".format(blob.name, blob.cache_control))
```

But when I put the code into the actual application, every time I execute it, it shows "Function execution took 340005 ms, finished with status:'timeout'". For this reason, I set the maximum timeout time to 540s, and the memory is 256MB, the execution result is still timed out.

For a novice, this problem has entangled me for a long time, so I want to ask if there is a problem with my code or is it caused by too many objects in my storage? Is there any way to make the function execute faster Some?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: how many blobs do you  have in your bucket?

Comment: There are about tens of thousands of files

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, every time the function is called you iterate over all existing blobs in the bucket and change their metadata. Do you really need to re-process them all every time? If you need to change metadata of each recently uploaded blob, you should consider using GCS notifications:

New file uploaded/created in the bucket -> Trigger GCS notification -> PubSub -> Trigger a Cloud Function to change the metadata.

That way, you would change the metadata for only one file at the time and Cloud Function can scale automatically to handle multiple files at the time (or you could process in batches).

GCS Notification: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

Example on how to enable GCS notification:

```
gsutil notification create -t TOPIC_NAME -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

The parameters -e OBJECT_FINALIZE, indicates that the notification will only happen once a blob has been created in the GCS.

Comment: Yes, every time you upload a new blob, you need to modify the metadata of all objects in the storage

Comment: I tried to use the pub/sub notification to trigger the function to execute the code, but the problem of "timeout" still occurs. Excuse me, if there are too many blobs in my storage, will it cause the function to execute too slowly? There are almost tens of thousands of blobs in my current storage

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is that you perform an API call to update the metadata of the blob. You have tens of thousands files, you perform tens of thousands API call. And even if it's very quick, it takes about 100ms per call (https handshake, processing/response) and therefore you reach the timeout.

To solve this problem, you have need to concurrently perform the API calls. 2 solutions

- Not so much scalale: In your code, perfom asynchronous calls to send several request in parallel. I don't know how to achieve that in Python, but in Go, it's efficient. You can perform hundreds of calls concurrently, and more if you increase your memory (to increase the CPU power). However, if the number of file increase, you will reach a limit at a time.
- Highly scalable: write a first function with only read the blobs in the bucket. Every a certain number of blobs, let say 500, you publish a message in PubSub (the base64 encoded of the 500th blob name). A second function listen the PubSub topic and for each message get the blobs and update them.

In the 2nd functions, you need to set the same number of blob to process than in the 1st one, let's say 500. Like that you process, over different Cloud Functions, chunk of 500 blobs.

The trick here is the following: the blob name base64 encoded. When you perform a `list_blob` add the parameter `page_token=<b64_blob_name>` like that

```
...
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, page_token=...)

for blob in blobs:
  ....
```

Indeed, the page token is the base64 blob name of the next file to process. Like that, you don't need to browse all your bucket every time, you only start from a defined point in each Cloud Function.